# Find a way to query different columns in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm building a kind of lexicon for my colleagues at the school where I work. I've searched an answer to this for some hours now but can't find it.

The reason for the columns and the x:es is that some words have two or more subjects and turns up in multiple courses. Some of my colleagues are convenient with the filter-tool while others aren't.

The thought is to get the words and the explanations in a list via a query. The rows (post) has some kind of crude tagging system based on subject and course. The colleagues wants to get a list of posts from two drop down menus, one for subject and one for course.

This is the layout of the spreadsheet:

```
 |           |Subject |Course  |                         |
 |Word       |Hi|Ge|Re|C1|C2|C3|Explanation              |  Concat..
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 |Jesus      |  |  | x|  | x|  |Son of God.              |Jesus-Son ...
 |Meander    |  | x|  |  |  | x|Bends in a river.        |Meander-Bend.
 |City State | x|  |  |  |  | x|State in ancient Greece. |City State...
 |Diaspora   | x|  | x| x|  |  |The time the Jewish p... |Diaspora-The.
```

How can I get the two drop down menus (Subject, Course) to generate a list from a query? The only column I need to output is the last Concat-column.

This is the actual query:

```
=QUERY(Begrepp!C2:BP;"select BN where [subject] = x and [course] = x ";1)
```

I want to replace `subject` and `course` with column-letters derived from the two drop down menus.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer. Maybe you might explain to me like I'm five?

Comment: Can you provide a better example output, I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in A1 through I6. Put the dropdown for Subject in K2 and the dropdown for Courses on L2. Copy this formula in M2:

=iferror(query(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((indirect(ADDRESS(3,match(K2,A2:G2,0),4)&":"&ADDRESS(100,match(K2,A2:G2,0),4))="x")*(indirect(ADDRESS(3,match(L2,A2:G2,0),4)&":"&ADDRESS(100,match(L2,A2:G2,0),4))="x"),$I$3:$I,"")),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null"),"No valid match")

I am attaching a shared spreadsheet that you can copy. It has a working copy of your data on Sheet1 and Sheet2 has a breakdown of the formula on pieces to help you understand what is going on. Sorry it can't be done with a simple query.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O8SzPR_cyI3kpYa7uFSDBRyWDthIlftUIXVOj5UnIVk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you! I did a workaround by putting a lot of if-statements in a cell to pull all the data from the different columns:`=if(L6="x";"M 1 ";"") & if(M6="x";"T 1 ";"") & if(N6="x";"O 1 ";"") & if(O6="x";"M 2 ";"") & if(P6="x";"T 2 ";"") & if(Q6="x";"O 2 ";"") & if(R6="x";"M 3 ";"") & if(S6="x";"T 3 ";"") &...` I will try your solution and get back.

Comment: To pull the data and create the text from the choices i created this: `=IFERROR(vlookup(A2;Listor!A2:B5;2)&char(10)&arrayformula(concatenate(QUERY(Begrepp!A3:BP;"select A, B, E where J contains """&A2&""" and K contains """&B2&"""" ;0)&char(10)));"Inga begrepp funna.")` It works but it's not elegant.

Comment: Because of local settings, you will probably need to change the "," in my formulas to ";".

Comment: Yes I know. I'm used to do do that. Not my fault that The US uses the comma and dot incorrect. ;-)

Comment: Thank you @ed-nelson It worked beautifully after some tweaking. It took me a while to figure out how to deal with sheet-references. 

`=iferror(
CONCATENATE(

query(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((indirect("Begrepp!"&ADDRESS(5;match(B2;Begrepp!F3:I3;0)+5;4)&":"&ADDRESS(1000;match(B2;Begrepp!F3:I3;0)+5;4))="x") *(indirect("Begrepp!"&ADDRESS(5;match(A2;Begrepp!J3:AO3;0)+9;4)&":"&ADDRESS(1000;match(A2;Begrepp!J3:AO3;0)+9;4))="x");Begrepp!A5:A&char(10)&Begrepp!B5:B&char(10)&char(10);""
));"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null"));"Hittade inga begrepp.")`

Comment: This might save you some time. Using Address from another sheet is a little tricky. The sheet name needs to be added as the fourth argument of Address for the first of both Addresses references. See Sheet3 of my shared spreadsheet for an example. If this works for you, please approve my answer. Thanks.

Comment: So approved. I'm a noob here so have mercy with me.

Tried to add sheet name in fourth argument but it added the sheet name to both line and row so I did this workaround instead.